# Regular Expression to extract a url included in a string

Tags: php, regex, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to match URIs in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82398/how-to-match-uris-in-text)
>   [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

I need to extract the URL to a zip file from a string that contains many URLs , using regexp (PHP).

A simple example should be helpful:

Target: extract the url http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.zip

Base string:

```
/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.zip&sa=U&ei=VpnIUP22Js blah /url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle&sa=U&ei=VpnIUP22Js blah /url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.rar&sa=U&ei=VpnIUP22Js
```

Update;
lets say the base string is

href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.zip">Some text /a>Some other text here a href="http://google.com/wiki/Kettle"> /a>

i need to extract the 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.zip

any method is ok...regex or not.

Comment: or rather of [How to match URIs in text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82398/how-to-match-uris-in-text)

Comment: Or one of the many others that talk about how to make that clickable, I bet there is a lot of regular expressions in all these duplicate QA materials.

Comment: Can't you split on `" blah "`, parse URL query string (and decodeURI!), get the `q` parameter and then filter for `.zip` extensions?

Comment: if everything is of the form "url then description" separated by a space(s) then forget the regex and just use a split function, you've no need to recognise whether it's a url or not because you have the position… _then_ you could parse the url host and path from the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex.  Regexes are not a magic wand that solve all problems related to strings.

Use `parse_url()` to break apart your URL and then use `explode` to break apart the query string on `&`.

```
$url = "http://example.com/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.zip&sa=U&ei=VpnIUP22Js";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
print "query is: $query\n";
$args = explode( '&', $query );
print_r( $args );
```

Running this gives:

```
query is: q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.zip&sa=U&ei=VpnIUP22Js
Array
(
    [0] => q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kettle.zip
    [1] => sa=U
    [2] => ei=VpnIUP22Js 
)
```

From there just walk through the array and find the one you want.

Comment: "Regexes are not a magic wand that solve all problems related to strings." +1 just for this.

Comment: @Iain: Go read my posting history.  I've been beating that drum for the past couple of weeks. :-)