# Web Crawler not following page's links

Tags: php, regex, web-crawler

I built a simple web crawler that echo's a page's contents after `<body>`. It does that fine, the only problem is that it is not following the links on the page to go to other pages that it recursively crawls.

In the output, I am only seeing the contents of the page that was manually given to start the crawler and no sign that it is following the links.

How can I get it to follow the links, crawl those pages, and echo their content?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ERROR );

define( "CRAWL_LIMIT_PER_DOMAIN", 50 );

$domains = array();

$urls = array();

function crawl( $url )
{
    global $domains, $urls;
    $parse = parse_url( $url );
    $domains[ $parse['host'] ]++;
    $urls[] = $url;

    $content = file_get_contents( $url );
    if ( $content === FALSE ){
        return;
    }

    $content = stristr($content, "<body>");
    preg_match_all( '/http:\/\/[^ "\']+/', $content, $matches );

    // do something with content.
    echo strip_tags($content);

    foreach( $matches[0] as $crawled_url ) {
        $parse = parse_url( $crawled_url );
        if ( count( $domains[ $parse['host'] ] ) < CRAWL_LIMIT_PER_DOMAIN && !in_array(   $crawled_url, $urls ) ) {
            sleep( 1 );
            crawl( $crawled_url );
        }
    }
}

crawl('http://the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html');
?>
```

**Update:** I'm assuming there is something wrong with the regex ( /http://[^ "\']+/ ). How can I implement a regex that follows all href's of all anchors whether they start with

```
http://
http:/www.
www.
https://
https://www.
```

or anything else (such as an absolute file-path like index.html ) ?
Or is there a better way to do this that regex?

Comment: So your regex doesn't work?

Comment: Wouldn't even say the regex is too far of, however links must not start with `http:` at all. You know what the Base URI is in HTML?

Comment: Use: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes, I am assuming it is the regex ( /http:\/\/[^ "\']+/ ).

Comment: What do you mean links must not start with http ? The links do. I know for sure one of them does. Visit the page http://www.the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html

Comment: @Userpassword Thank you for sharing, but I want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Regex is ok error_reporting 0, then try print_r on arrays, and use sqlite

Comment: @Userpassword How do I do that? I don't even know what sqlite is

Comment: use google, try debug by print_r, check arrays, user array_uniq on domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should (as ususal) first of all make up your mind what you're actually doing.

As you outline in your question you're doing a text-search for URL patterns of the HTTP protocol. A common regex normally includes the `https:` URI scheme as well:

```
~https?://\S*~
```

That is everything until the first whitepspace. this normally does the job for detecting HTTP URLs of a wider range within a string. If you need something more advanced see the Stackover Q&A about making links of texts clickable:

- [How to match URIs in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82398/367456)
- [How to extract http links from a paragraph and store them in a array on php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6861324/367456)

This still will not solve all of your crawler problems. For two reasons:

1. Character encoding: If you want to properly do that, you need to know the correct character encoding of the string and make the regular expression fitting for it.
2. That is text. Websites not only consist of text but also of HTML which carries its own semantics.

So actually doing text-analysis alone is not enough. You also need to parse HTML. That means you need to take the Base URI and resolve each other URI inside the document against it to obtain the list of all absolute links in that document.

You find this outlined in the following whitepaper:

- [5. Reference Resolution in](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5) [RFC3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

For PHP the two most stable components to work with for this are:

1. [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) - A PHP extension to parse XML and HTML documents. Here you are looking for parsing HTML documents naturally.
2. [`Net_Url2`](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/) - A PEAR extension to deal with URLs including RFC3986 conform reference resolution (the differences to the previous version you can safely ignore, the standard is pretty stable as the PHP library is, two minor bugs in very narrow and specific cases are still open but have patches).

Comment: So, let me see if I understand you correctly: `~https?://\S*~` is not good enough as it only works for https:// links and not ones that start with http:// or www or the absolute file-paths like index.html. Then `!(https?://[^\s]+)!` doesn't work either because it is missing the encoding of the content and because of the HTML's semantics.
What one needs to do is parse the html, one way is with DOMDocument.

Comment: Am I correct so far? Then, my question is how can I use DOMDocument to get the value of all href attributes of all anchors in a page?

Comment: Slowly. `s?` - see http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html - so not correct about https only. However, sure www and the relative paths are not captured. See the first list of links if you want to take the text-analysis up to a level where it starts to hurt. For relative links, better take an HTML parser as outlined in the second part of the answer.

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that part. I see how it captures http:// and https://. What's the difference between `~https?://\S*~` and `(https?://[^\s]+)!`? I saw the HTML parser DOMDocument, but have no idea on how to use it. Do you have any advice or tips on how to use it to extract the href values of the anchors ? Should I start a new question?

Comment: @IMUXIxD: Regexes: No difference, both are describing nearly the same just in different ways (there are still a difference: * is zero or more, + means one or more. Consult the manual or the regular-expressions.info website with anything regex related, they explain this well. For parsing with DOMDocument asking is pretty limited, it's more to learn about it. In the end its more the understanding than the asking. Improving search skills is always useful [problem with adding root path using php domdocument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7442432/367456) . Also watch for the column on the right on SO.

Comment: Yes, I've been reading the manual. Thank you for linking that. This is probably a completely wrong and badly written regex, but I was trying to write one that would match anything that starts with http://, https://. www, and ends at a ' or ": `(http(s)?://)?(www)?`. Thank you for link on DOMDocument and for all your help.

Comment: That is `(wwww|https?://)`. And when you learn regex, create youself a PHP file to test things against strings. That way you can try and learn faster.

Comment: okay, thank you. one more question is there supposed to be 4 w's or only 3? After this, I will mark your answer and correct and play with Dom Document.

Comment: @IMUXIxD: The common subdomain is `www` with three `w`, the abbreviation for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web

Comment: That is what I thought. Thank you for all the help. I am going to look into html parsing some more.